# Execute a task on subfolders within a folder

Tags: python, directory, glob, os.walk

I have a folder_X that has multiple subfolders within it. I need to execute my code on all of the files within the subfolder, while keeping them in their respective folders.

I have tried glob and os.walk but can't get either to work

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of how you tried to make it work? This could help to clarify your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.